# NuGet packages Access Denied error during TeamCity Build

Tags: windows, nuget, teamcity, windows-server-2008

When running a build configuration on our TeamCity server with,

Build Steps:
 1. Delete NuGet packages folder 
 2. NuGet Installer - on this step we are getting multiple errors such as:

[restore] Access to the path '[absolute path]\packages\Microsoft.1.0.0\lib\AjaxControlToolkit.dll' is denied.

Most packages install successfully, but a few do not. Accessing the path through windows Explorer gives the error:

Location is not available
[absolute path]\packages\Microsoft.1.0.0\lib is not accessible.
Access is denied.

[image: Windows Error]

I have looked at the Sharing and security setting for the parent folders, but can't see any reason why access should be denied to some random folders. I recently made a Sharing change to a parent folder just before this error through:

properties > sharing > advanced sharing

but have since changed it back to the previous state.

Using:
TeamCity Enterprise 9.0.3
NuGet 2.8.3
Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Comment: Have you tried running procmon to see what's going on under the hood?  You can filter down the results by path, partial path or executable to see the filesystem activity.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx